# Upgrade 5.6.3 to 6.7.1

Tags: sonarqube

We are trying to upgrade our current SonarQube from 5.6.3. to 6.7.1 
We have upgrade our SQL Server to 2014 and 5.6.3 has been tested and it has been working fine when I try to start the 6.7.1 server. It shows the Warning database needs an upgrade but the process seems to be running.

Is the issue because of the plugins which we are supporting or the version of database. I am attaching all the logs that got generated.

Database version : Microsoft SQL Server2014(MSSM studio 12.0.5207.0)
Plugin version : 
SonarJava : sonar-java-plugin-4.6.0.8784
C#        : sonar-csharp-plugin-5.10.1.1411

Does plugin version has to play any role ( I doubt as it is highly unlikely)

Let me know in case any further details are required.

Please advice.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing [the step](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) where you have SonarQube upgrade it's own database schema. Specifically, navigate to `[your SonarQube URL]/setup` and click the button on that screen. That triggers SonarQube to make the database changes required to support your new version.